Why does SIESTA 5.0.1 fail to run in parallel but working in serial execution?
I am trying out SIESTA for the first time and while it seems to run without any problem for a serial execution, I am encountering an error everytime I am assigning more than 1 processor. So, the following works without any problem.
siesta ZnS.fdf > ZnS.serial.out
But when I am trying
mpirun -np 10 siesta ZnS.fdf > ZnS.parallel.out
after successful initialization, it is stopping right after the SCF calculation starts. I am not changing anything in the input. Both of the output files are given below. The error message I am receiving on the terminal is:
*** The MPI_Comm_c2f() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** The MPI_Comm_c2f() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
[unam-abdul:1035887] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
*** Your MPI job will now abort.
[unam-abdul:1035890] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

The error file ZnS.parallel.out
[...]
************************ Begin: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS ************************
************************ End: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS **************************


                     ====================================
                        Single-point calculation
                     ====================================

superc: Internal auxiliary supercell:     3 x     3 x     3  =      27
superc: Number of atoms, orbitals, and projectors:   1728  27648  31104

outcell: Unit cell vectors (Ang):
       10.774732    0.000000    0.000000
        0.000000   10.774732    0.000000
        0.000000    0.000000   10.774732

outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :   10.774732   10.774732   10.774732
outcell: Cell angles (23,13,12) (deg):     90.0000     90.0000     90.0000
outcell: Cell volume (Ang**3)        :   1250.8908
<dSpData1D:S at geom step 0
  <sparsity:sparsity for geom step 0
    nrows_g=1024 nrows=128 sparsity=.0376 nnzs=39436, refcount: 7>
  <dData1D:(new from dSpData1D) n=39436, refcount: 1>
refcount: 1>
new_DM -- step:     1
Initializing Density Matrix...

Attempting to read DM from file... Failed...
DM filled with atomic data:
<dSpData2D:DM initialized from atoms
  <sparsity:sparsity for geom step 0
    nrows_g=1024 nrows=128 sparsity=.0376 nnzs=39436, refcount: 8>
  <dData2D:DM n=39436 m=1, refcount: 1>
refcount: 1>
No. of atoms with KB's overlaping orbs in proc 0. Max # of overlaps:     104     119

InitMesh: MESH = 96 x 96 x 96 = 884736
InitMesh: Mesh cutoff (required, used) =   200.000   219.397 Ry
New grid distribution [1]: sub = 2
New grid distribution [2]: sub = 2
New grid distribution [3]: sub = 2
Setting up quadratic distribution...

The successful ZnS.serial.out
[...]
************************ Begin: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS ************************
************************ End: TS CHECKS AND WARNINGS **************************


                     ====================================
                        Single-point calculation
                     ====================================

superc: Internal auxiliary supercell:     3 x     3 x     3  =      27
superc: Number of atoms, orbitals, and projectors:   1728  27648  31104

outcell: Unit cell vectors (Ang):
       10.774732    0.000000    0.000000
        0.000000   10.774732    0.000000
        0.000000    0.000000   10.774732

outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :   10.774732   10.774732   10.774732
outcell: Cell angles (23,13,12) (deg):     90.0000     90.0000     90.0000
outcell: Cell volume (Ang**3)        :   1250.8908
<dSpData1D:S at geom step 0
  <sparsity:sparsity for geom step 0
    nrows_g=1024 nrows=1024 sparsity=.3449 nnzs=361664, refcount: 7>
  <dData1D:(new from dSpData1D) n=361664, refcount: 1>
refcount: 1>
new_DM -- step:     1
Initializing Density Matrix...

Attempting to read DM from file... Succeeded...
DM from file:
<dSpData2D:IO-DM: ZnS.DM
  <sparsity:IO-DM: ZnS.DM
    nrows_g=1024 nrows=1024 sparsity=.3449 nnzs=361664, refcount: 1>
  <dData2D:(new from dSpData2D) n=361664 m=1, refcount: 1>
refcount: 1>
DM to be used:
<dSpData2D:Re-structured SpM
  <sparsity:sparsity for geom step 0
    nrows_g=1024 nrows=1024 sparsity=.3449 nnzs=361664, refcount: 8>
  <dData2D:(new in restruct) n=361664 m=1, refcount: 1>
refcount: 1>
No. of atoms with KB's overlaping orbs in proc 0. Max # of overlaps:     166     119

InitMesh: MESH = 96 x 96 x 96 = 884736
InitMesh: Mesh cutoff (required, used) =   200.000   219.397 Ry
New grid distribution [1]: sub = 2

stepf: Fermi-Dirac step function

siesta: Program's energy decomposition (eV):
siesta: Ebs     =    -21038.723183
siesta: Eions   =    225243.187066
siesta: Ena     =     11474.688948
siesta: Ekin    =     89732.582062
siesta: Enl     =    -44526.720508
siesta: Eso     =         0.000000
siesta: Edftu   =         0.000000
siesta: DEna    =       -29.051006
siesta: DUscf   =       123.237777
siesta: DUext   =         0.000000
siesta: Ex      =    -21711.107989
siesta: Ec      =     -1291.636392
siesta: Exc     =    -23002.744381
siesta: EbV     =         0.000000
siesta: eta*DQ  =         0.000000
siesta: Emadel  =         0.000000
siesta: Emeta   =         0.000000
siesta: Emolmec =         0.000000
siesta: Ekinion =         0.000000
siesta: Eharris =   -189424.078651
siesta: Etot    =   -191471.194174
siesta: FreeEng =   -191471.194174

        iscf     Eharris(eV)        E_KS(eV)     FreeEng(eV)     dDmax    Ef(eV) dHmax(eV)
   scf:    1  -189424.078651  -191471.194174  -191471.194174  1.796251 -1.366365 42.563132
timer: Routine,Calls,Time,% = IterSCF        1     122.194  91.70
   scf:    2  -192825.911585  -192230.945005  -192230.945005  0.776728 -2.153271 22.649627
   scf:    3  -192518.737102  -192431.070216  -192431.070216  0.611270 -1.893501  1.514973
   scf:    4  -192434.854018  -192433.088676  -192433.088676  0.035762 -1.628727  0.934490
   scf:    5  -192434.731029  -192434.056431  -192434.056431  0.043234 -1.414297  0.232083
   scf:    6  -192434.149312  -192434.110543  -192434.110543  0.009218 -1.395403  0.115521
   scf:    7  -192434.119126  -192434.116547  -192434.116547  0.003406 -1.393476  0.052966
   scf:    8  -192434.118044  -192434.117334  -192434.117334  0.000924 -1.397287  0.027477
   scf:    9  -192434.118186  -192434.117799  -192434.117799  0.000989 -1.400798  0.007007
   scf:   10  -192434.117921  -192434.117864  -192434.117864  0.000401 -1.401537  0.003496
   scf:   11  -192434.117897  -192434.117883  -192434.117883  0.000329 -1.401901  0.001669
   scf:   12  -192434.117885  -192434.117884  -192434.117884  0.000122 -1.401850  0.000896
   scf:   13  -192434.117884  -192434.117884  -192434.117884  0.000058 -1.401666  0.000850

SCF Convergence by DM+H criterion
max |DM_out - DM_in|         :     0.0000576040
max |H_out - H_in|      (eV) :     0.0008504884
SCF cycle converged after 13 iterations

Using DM_out to compute the final energy and forces
No. of atoms with KB's overlaping orbs in proc 0. Max # of overlaps:     166     119

siesta: E_KS(eV) =          -192434.1179

siesta: E_KS - E_eggbox =   -192434.1179

siesta: Atomic forces (eV/Ang):
----------------------------------------
   Tot    0.000001    0.000001    0.000001
----------------------------------------
   Max    0.000000
   Res    0.000000    sqrt( Sum f_i^2 / 3N )
----------------------------------------
   Max    0.000000    constrained

Stress tensor Voigt[x,y,z,yz,xz,xy] (kbar):      155.20      155.20      155.20        0.00        0.00        0.00
(Free)E + p*V (eV/cell)  -192555.2933
Target enthalpy (eV/cell)  -192434.1179
Computing bands...

siesta: Program's energy decomposition (eV):
siesta: Ebs     =    -30095.269146
siesta: Eions   =    225243.187066
siesta: Ena     =     11474.688948
siesta: Ekin    =     85105.609510
siesta: Enl     =    -41646.602672
siesta: Eso     =         0.000000
siesta: Edftu   =         0.000000
siesta: DEna    =       226.012922
siesta: DUscf   =       236.777319
siesta: DUext   =         0.000000
siesta: Ex      =    -21318.565578
siesta: Ec      =     -1268.851267
siesta: Exc     =    -22587.416846
siesta: EbV     =         0.000000
siesta: eta*DQ  =         0.000000
siesta: Emadel  =         0.000000
siesta: Emeta   =         0.000000
siesta: Emolmec =         0.000000
siesta: Ekinion =         0.000000
siesta: Eharris =   -192434.117884
siesta: Etot    =   -192434.117884
siesta: FreeEng =   -192434.117884

siesta: Final energy (eV):
siesta:  Band Struct. =  -30095.269146
siesta:       Kinetic =   85105.609510
siesta:       Hartree =   80238.731231
siesta:         Edftu =       0.000000
siesta:       Eso     =       0.000000
siesta:    Ext. field =       0.000000
siesta:         Exch. =  -21318.565578
siesta:         Corr. =   -1268.851267
siesta:     Bulk bias =       0.000000
siesta:   Exch.-corr. =  -22587.416846
siesta:  Ion-electron = -250626.252495
siesta:       Ion-ion =  -84564.789285
siesta:       Ekinion =       0.000000
siesta: D3 dispersion =       0.000000
siesta:         Total = -192434.117884
siesta:         Fermi =      -1.401666

siesta: Stress tensor (static) (eV/Ang**3):
siesta:     0.096871    0.000000    0.000000
siesta:     0.000000    0.096871    0.000000
siesta:     0.000000    0.000000    0.096871

siesta: Cell volume =       1250.890766 Ang**3

siesta: Pressure (static):
siesta:                Solid            Molecule  Units
siesta:          -0.00105506         -0.00105506  Ry/Bohr**3
siesta:          -0.09687129         -0.09687129  eV/Ang**3
siesta:        -155.20492415       -155.20492391  kBar
(Free)E+ p_basis*V_orbitals  =     -192409.848911
(Free)Eharris+ p_basis*V_orbitals  =     -192409.848911

cite: Please see "ZnS.bib" for an exhaustive BiBTeX file.
cite: Please clearly indicate Siesta version in published work: 5.0.1
cite: This calculation has made use of the following articles
cite: which are encouraged to be cited in a published work.
        Primary SIESTA paper
          DOI: www.doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/14/11/302


timer: Elapsed wall time (sec) =    1629.158
timer: CPU execution times (sec):

Routine            Calls   Time/call    Tot.time        %
siesta                 1    1628.686    1628.686   100.00
Setup                  1       0.145       0.145     0.01
bands                  3      21.200      63.601     3.91
KSV_init               1       0.000       0.000     0.00
IterGeom               1    1564.905    1564.905    96.08
geom_init              1      10.921      10.921     0.67
state_init             1       1.558       1.558     0.10
hsparse                1       0.045       0.045     0.00
overlap                1       1.450       1.450     0.09
Setup_H0               1       7.596       7.596     0.47
naefs                  2       0.001       0.001     0.00
MolMec                 2       0.000       0.000     0.00
kinefsm                2       0.784       1.569     0.10
nlefsm                 2       2.006       4.012     0.25
DHSCF_Init             1       2.282       2.282     0.14
DHSCF1                 1       0.011       0.011     0.00
INITMESH               1       0.000       0.000     0.00
DHSCF2                 1       2.271       2.271     0.14
REMESH                 1       0.179       0.179     0.01
REORD                 45       0.002       0.068     0.00
PHION                  1       1.710       1.710     0.10
COMM_BSC              63       0.001       0.085     0.01
POISON                16       0.208       3.329     0.20
fft                   32       0.097       3.117     0.19
setup_H               14       2.006      28.087     1.72
DHSCF                 15       2.401      36.021     2.21
DHSCF3                15       2.001      30.021     1.84
rhoofd                15       0.701      10.514     0.65
XC                    15       0.548       8.225     0.51
GXC-CellXC            15       0.543       8.150     0.50
gridxc@cellXC         15       0.543       8.150     0.50
vmat                  15       0.522       7.834     0.48
IterSCF               13     118.895    1545.637    94.90
compute_dm            13     116.860    1519.179    93.28
diagon                13     116.858    1519.152    93.27
c-eigval             722       0.369     266.677    16.37
c-buildHS            722       0.008       5.791     0.36
cdiag               1294       0.480     620.482    38.10
cdiag1              1294       0.032      40.963     2.52
cdiag2              1294       0.107     138.360     8.50
cdiag3              1294       0.322     416.405    25.57
c-eigvec             572       0.636     363.639    22.33
cdiag4               572       0.038      21.572     1.32
c-buildD             572       1.664     952.072    58.46
MIXER                 12       0.005       0.065     0.00
PostSCF                1       8.345       8.345     0.51
DHSCF4                 1       5.999       5.999     0.37
dfscf                  1       5.743       5.743     0.35
overfsm                1       0.081       0.081     0.00
writeHSX               1       0.004       0.004     0.00
state_analysis         1       0.000       0.000     0.00
siesta_move            1       0.000       0.000     0.00
Analysis               1      63.629      63.629     3.91
optical                1       0.000       0.000     0.00
  

>> End of run:   2-JUL-2024  19:47:44
Job completed

EDIT: According to @nickpapior's suggestion, I am adding the compilation procedure. At first, I installed the following libraries in my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
sudo apt install build-essential gfortran cmake libopenmpi-dev liblapack-dev 
sudo apt install libscalapack-openmpi-dev libnetcdff-dev openmpi-bin
sudo apt install libblas-dev libscalapack-mpi-dev
sudo apt install libhdf5-dev libhdf5-mpi-dev libnetcdf-dev libnetcdff-dev netcdf-bin
sudo apt install diffutils patch curl wget readline-common

Then I downloaded the source and used cmake to install SIESTA:
cd /home/abdul/opt/
wget https://gitlab.com/siesta-project/siesta/-/releases/5.0.1/downloads/siesta-5.0.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf siesta-5.0.1.tar.gz
mv siesta-5.0.1 siesta
cmake -S. -B_build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/abdul/opt/siesta -DSCALAPACK_LIBRARY="-lscalapack-openmpi"
cmake --build _build -j 10
cmake --install _build
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/siesta/bin >> ~/.bashrc 
source ~/.bashrc

EDIT 2: output of the ldd /path/to/siesta command
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd59cb5000)
    libnetcdff.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdff.so.7 (0x000072616dea7000)
    libgfortran.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x000072616be00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x000072616c119000)
    libmvec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1 (0x000072616bd03000)
    libmpifort.so.12 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.13/lib/libmpifort.so.12 (0x000072616b800000)
    libscalapack-openmpi.so.2.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libscalapack-openmpi.so.2.1 (0x000072616b200000)
    libmkl_gf_lp64.so.2 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.2/lib/libmkl_gf_lp64.so.2 (0x000072616a400000)
    libmkl_gnu_thread.so.2 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.2/lib/libmkl_gnu_thread.so.2 (0x0000726168a00000)
    libmkl_core.so.2 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2024.2/lib/libmkl_core.so.2 (0x0000726164a00000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x000072616de59000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000072616c0f9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000726164600000)
    libnetcdf.so.19 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so.19 (0x000072616bbac000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x000072616b7b8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000072616df61000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x000072616de54000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x000072616de4d000)
    libmpi.so.12 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.13/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x000072615a600000)
    liblapack.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3 (0x0000726159e00000)
    libblas.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3 (0x000072616b19e000)
    libmpi.so.40 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40 (0x000072616b067000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x000072616de48000)
    libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100 (0x000072616b042000)
    libhdf5_serial.so.103 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.103 (0x0000726159a00000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x000072616a359000)
    libopenblas.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007261575b0000)
    libopen-rte.so.40 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.40 (0x0000726164943000)
    libopen-pal.so.40 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.40 (0x000072616a2a6000)
    libhwloc.so.15 => /opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.13/env/../lib/intel64/gcc4.8/libhwloc.so.15 (0x0000726157200000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x0000726156c00000)
    libsz.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so.2 (0x000072616c0f0000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007261689e4000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007261689ba000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x0000726168999000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x000072616897a000)
    libssh.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x00007261648d6000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007261648c2000)
    libssl.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x000072616455c000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x000072616486e000)
    libldap-2.5.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap-2.5.so.0 (0x00007261644fd000)
    liblber-2.5.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.5.so.0 (0x000072616c0db000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x000072615a531000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x000072616b7aa000)
    libevent_core-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_core-2.1.so.7 (0x0000726164839000)
    libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent_pthreads-2.1.so.7 (0x000072616a2a1000)
    libaec.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaec.so.0 (0x0000726164830000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x0000726157056000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000726156a15000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007261644b5000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x000072616446f000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x000072615752e000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000726157463000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000726164440000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x000072616482a000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x000072615a523000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x000072615a508000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x000072615a4e5000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007261568da000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x000072615a4cd000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x000072615a4c6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000726159dec000)
    libffi.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x0000726159ddf000)


Likely you are mixing the shared libraries at runtime vs compile time. It would be helpful to know how you compiled it, and how the used libraries are?

@nickpapior I have added the compilation procedure and the libraries that I used as an edit to the post.

Also show ldd siesta to get an idea.

@nickpapior done.

This problem happens because you are mixing MPI versions.
While you think you are compiling against OpenMPI, what happens is quite different.
The key-point here is the following:
$> ldd siesta | grep mpifort
    libmpifort.so.12 => /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.13/lib/libmpifort.so.12 (0x000072616b800000)
$> ldd siesta | grep scalapack
    libscalapack-openmpi.so.2.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libscalapack-openmpi.so.2.1 (0x000072616b200000)

this means you are compiling with Intel MPI (this is MPICH based).
And you are then linking in OpenMPI dependent libraries.
This always results in crashes with exactly your error-message. So, you have to fix this when compiling Siesta. Ensuring the build is picking up the correct MPI compiler depending on what you want.
The simplest might just be to not source the intel variables so Siesta never sees them. But it depends on what you want to achieve.

I accepted the answer since it correctly points out to the problem (and hence answers the question as it is written). However, after several trials I still cannot run siesta in parallel. I am following this official tutorial step by step with no success.
